# How to retrieve rows, based on column from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-in

I have 2 tables.

Table 1

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Gene  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| G_Cor | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| OMID  | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Sym_A | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Sym_B | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Int_Ty| varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now i have retrieve Sym_A and Sym_B from table 2which are same as Gene from table 1 and i have to display one separate table.

Comment: Use a join like this `SELECT b.Sym_A, b.Sym_B FROM <table1> a INNER JOIN <table2> b ON a.Gene = b.Sym_A OR a.Gene = b.Sym_B`

Comment: put the column condition in where clause of your sql.

Comment: Or you may provide some data for each table to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply:-)  But i am not getting the right answer. In Table 1, i have nearly 3500 entries. In table2, I have 250880 entries. Now I have to check whether these 3500 entries are in Sym_A OR Sym_B in table 2 or not? 
But i am getting 150089 rows in table one.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want a query that retrieves the rows from table 2 which have
 `Sym_A=Gene OR Sym_B=Gene`, since your question is not so clear (If you want them to satisfy both just change the OR for an AND)
In that case the following query would work:

```
SELECT t2.Sym_A, t2.Sym_B
FROM Table2 t2, Table1 t1
WHERE (t2.Sym_A=t1.Gene) OR (t2.Sym_B=t1.Gene);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.`Sym_A`,t2.`Sym_B`
FROM table 2 t2
JOIN table t1 ON (t2.`Sym_A`=t1.`Gene`) OR (t2.`Sym_B`=t1.`Gene`);
```